# Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes - aws cli error

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I am running the below awscli command in a bash script through teamcity step

```
 #!/bin/bash 
  repo=%env.RepoName%
  echo "repo is ${repo}"
  tags=%env.Tags%
  echo "tags are ${tags}"
  aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${repo} --tags '${tags}'
```

where `%env.RepoName%` and `%env.Tags%` are teamcity variables with values `sample-repo` and `[{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"dept","Value":"finance"}]` respectively. However when the aws cli command runs it errors out with the below error

`Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

However if i pass in the value of `%env.Tags%` as `'[{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"dept","Value":"finance"}]'` with the single quotes and exclude the `''` from the tags property in the aws cli command it runs without issues.

What is that I am missing and is there a recommended way to fix this?

Comment: Single quotes suppress expansion, so you're literally sending `${tags}` and not its contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: @Aserre and Benjamin Thank you. The above link explains why this is not working. But I am still not sure how I would fix my particular issue. Do you have thoughts, please?

Comment: In other words, Is there a way I can exclude `' '` when passing the input and still make the aws-cli command work within the bash script?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep the double quotes by escaping them with a `\`. You may need to write `sed` to do this:

```
tags="[{\"Key\":\"env\",\"Value\":\"dev\"},\"Key\":\"dept\",\"Value\":\"finance\"}]"
```

Once it is done, verify the command using `echo` to check if the quotes are preserved.

```
echo aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${repo} --tags "${tags}"                         
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name sample-repo --tags [{"Key":"env","Value":"dev"},{"Key":"dept","Value":"finance"}]
```

Another way is using Short hand syntax. If you can get the tag keys/values separately, this syntax seems cleaner.

```
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${repo} --tags Key=env,Value=dev Key=dept,Value=finance
```